# Avoid blank line removal from xml file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Basically the problem is original xml file (`$myFilePath`) has blank lines in the file however while saving the xml file the blank lines are getting removed.

How to avoid the removal of blank lines from the file while saving it?

Below is what i have tried -

```
$myXmlDocument = [xml] (Get-Content -Path $myFilePath) # File ready style-1
$myXmlDocument = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($myFilePath)) # File ready style-2

$myXmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = $true #additional setting to preserver the format

#performing some string match and update. without the update also having same issue of blank line removal while saving.

$WadiAPConfigXmlDocument.Save($myFilePath) # saving the file
```

Comment: Why are blank lines in the file important to you?

Answer (score 0):

After reading from.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace?view=netcore-3.1

Remarks
This property determines how white space is handled during the load and save process.
If `PreserveWhitespace` is `true` before `Load` or `LoadXml` is called, white space nodes are preserved; otherwise, if this property is `false`, significant white space is preserved, white space is not.
If `PreserveWhitespace` is `true` before Save is called, white space in the document is preserved in the output; otherwise, if this property is `false`, `XmlDocument` auto-indents the output.

The first paragraph in the remarks section, should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the `PreserveWhitespace` property *before* loading the file:

```
# Create XmlDocument object and configure PreserveWhitespace
$xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
$xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true

# Load the document
$xmlDoc.Load($myFilePath)
# or 
$xmlDoc.LoadXml($(Get-Content $myFilePath -Raw))
```